# Images or functioning websites for portfolio?

Tags: website-design, portfolio

I am new web designer, should I include images or functioning websites in my portfolio?

*All of my designs are personal projects* that I have designed and built using html, css and javascript. By personal projects, I mean designs of generic website ideas: an e-commerce site, a hotel site, a travel site, etc.

Are images enough? Or should I include links to pages to demonstrate my ability to build my designs?

Comment: How are the personal projects hosted? Are they on the same server your main website is on?

Comment: Also one very important thing to remember is browser compatibility. You may not always be presenting on a newer browser (especially if you have not coded for fallbacks).

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest images should be enough to show proper UX/UI and a concept.

If there's specific functionality that you're looking to sell based off of (like jQuery calculator or advanced animation), then include a link to the live site, but honestly - only if you control it or can be sure it's maintained.

I learned long ago that pointing to sites from a Portfolio relies too much on the client maintaining that site, not screwing it up, and a thousand other factors...  Images look great in a portfolio, but what will kill your sell will be a link to a dead site, non-working demo, or something that a client has messed up.

So I'd actually recommend if you want to demo an interactive design, you should make a video of it and put THAT in your portfolio along with images of different pages.

Good luck!

Comment: Very good answer!